# Is it possible to enable 1.5x scaling using HiDPI on OS X?

Tags: macos, resolution

I use a Mac Mini on a 46" 1080p TV and using native resolution the UI is too small, and using HiDPI the UI is too big.

Is there a way to hack the OS X to enable 150% scaling instead of 100% and 200% ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike previous attempts at OS X resolution independence, HiDPI mode has a fixed 2x scaling factor. There's no way to change that scale factor, nor would I expect things to work well even if you could. In fact, prior to 10.7.3 or .4, HiDPI still had some bugs here and there.

There's a [good section on resolution independence](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2011/07/mac-os-x-10-7/14/#hi-dpi) in John Siracusa's Lion review at Ars Technica if you want a bit more detail.

Comment: I just hope they will enable this in a future version as most HDTV are 1080 and that's wrong for both 1x and 2x. Only a ~1.5 would be appropriate for them.

Comment: On a side note, I've never understood the need to use TVs as displays. The dot pitch means that if you're close enough to read UI text everything's pixelated, and if you're far away to not see pixels you can't read the UI. Get a proper $100–$150 display if possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible as it would result in a significantly distorted image with loss of image data. There is no way to accurately display one dot over 1.5 x 1.5 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you would like to have your information displayed in 1080p, I am low vision and use my mac mini server on a 42" vizio, if you right click or two finger tap (with a magic trackpad) on the tool bar of safari, mail and many other apps you will get a menu to hide tool bar and an option to customize tool bar, select customize tool bar then drag the little A and big A icon onto the tool bar this will allow you to enlarge the element inside of safari (keystrokes are command = or - on the short keyboard, you can use the + or - on the num pad of the long keyboard). For my lcd it takes three or four clicks of the big A, or three or four clicks of command +, this will display the page as it should, if I need further enlargement I will use pinch to zoom on the trackpad and two finger slide left or right to move the element to be able to read all the text on the screen. This option is not available with the app store or iTunes.

When the above options are not available or I need to read the tool bar or menus I use the accessibility feature in ML or Universal Access in Lion or earlier. Open system preferences select accessibility in ML,  then select zoom and enable the box for use keyboard shortcuts to zoom (this mode enlarges the whole screen not just the element inside the app) the keystrokes are option command = to enlarge or option command - to decress with the short keyboard (if you have the long keyboard you can use option command + or - on the num pad). You can also select more options and use the maximum zoom slider for a one click default zoom option, use the same keystrokes option command = or + to zoom out and option command - to zoom back in. You will have to play with this to find the zoom size you need.

Sorry I do not know how to include pictures or screenshots if someone could edit it might help. I hope this has helped.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is [possible](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1568657):

First you need to get [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/indexSRX4.html).

After installation, you then click System Preferences > Other > SwitchResX > select your Mac / Monitor from the right column -> Custom Resolution > and click + button to add a new resolution.

Now you need to select "Scaled resolution" inside the select option field & enter the resolution inside the scaled to Text field. So lets say if you want a 1920 x 1080 Hidpi setting, you need to create a custom 3840 x 2160 etc.

After all, just click save and then restart it, once you restart your mac, you should be able to see the new hidpi setting under display setting.

Comment: Could you provide information here not just a link